# Over metric spaces, must inverses of continuous functions be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

I am reading baby Rudin chapter 4 and came across the following theorem:

> Suppose $f$ is bijective and continuous from $X$ to $Y$, where $X$ is compact, then its inverse is continuous.

I perfectly understand the proof, however I am unsure why must $X$ be compact? I tried to find a counterexample when $X$ is not compact but couldn't find one. Would the theorem still be true if $X$ is not compact?

Comment: No, and the standard counterexample is $f:[0,2\pi)\to S^1\subset \Bbb{C}$, $f(t)=e^{it}$. The inverse function is the “angle” function mapping into $[0,2\pi)$, and this is discontinuous at the point $1\in\Bbb{C}$. Or if you think of $\Bbb{C}=\Bbb{R}^2$, then $f(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ and its inverse is discontinuous at $(1,0)$. There are billions of questions about this function on the site, in case you fail to prove yourself that the inverse isn’t continuous.

Comment: An even simpler counter-example is the identity map from $\mathbb R$ with the discrete metric into $\mathbb R$ with the usual metric.